# \app\src\main\res\layout\activity_login.xml: AAPT: error: file failed to compile

Tags: java

I have no idea why but my login_activity will not build and run. I cannot get onto my next stage of making my app but I cannot move on as it keeps giving me this error.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="20dp"
    android:background="#7ed957"
    tools:context=".LoginActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:text="Login"
        android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
        android:textSize="25sp" />

    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TabLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:id="@+id/emailET"
        app:passwordToggleEnabled="true">

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:hint="email"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true" />
    </com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TabLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:id="@+id/passwordTIL"
        android:layout_below="@id/emailET"
        app:passwordToggleEnabled="true">

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:hint="password"
            android:layout_below="@id/emailET"
            app:passwordToggleEnabled="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

        </com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout>


    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Login"
        android:layout_below="@id/passwordTIL"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        style="@style/Base.CardView"
        android:id="@+id/login_btn"
        />

    <!---TextView: Click go to RegisterActivity--->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/nothave_accountTv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Don't have an account? Register Now"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:textColor="@color/colorBlack" />

    <!---TextView: Show dialog to recover password--->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/recoverPassTv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:text="Forgot Password?"
        android:layout_below="@+id/login_btn" />

    <!---GoogleSignInBtn: Sign in with google account--->
    <com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton
        android:id="@+id/googleLoginBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/recoverPassTv">
    </com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton>


</RelativeLayout>
```

This is where the error is happening saying: 2x errors of

> app\src\main\res\layout\activity_login.xml:71: AAPT: error: not
>   well-formed (invalid token).

My LoginActivity.java is

```
    package com.connex.connexsocial;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBar;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.InputType;
import android.util.Patterns;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignIn;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInAccount;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInClient;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthCredential;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider;

import java.security.PublicKey;

public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 100;
    GoogleSignInClient mGoogleSignInClient;
    //views
    EditText mEmailET, mPasswordTIL;
    TextView notHaveAccountTv, mRecoverPassTv;
    Button mLoginBtn;
    SignInButton mGoogleLoginBtn;

    //Declare an instance of FirebaseAuth
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;

    //progress dialog
    ProgressDialog pd;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        //Actionbar and its title
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setTitle("Login");

        //Enable back button
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

        //before mAuth
        // Configure Google Sign In
        GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
                .requestEmail()
                .build();
                mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this,gso);

        //In the onCreate() method, initialize the FirebaseAuth instance.
        // Initialize Firebase Auth
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        //init
        mEmailET = findViewById(R.id.emailET);
        mPasswordTIL = findViewById(R.id.passwordTIL);
        notHaveAccountTv = findViewById(R.id.nothave_accountTv);
        mRecoverPassTv = findViewById(R.id.recoverPassTv);
        mLoginBtn = findViewById(R.id.login_btn);
        mGoogleLoginBtn = findViewById(R.id.googleLoginBtn);

        //login button click
        mLoginBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //input data
                String email = mEmailET.getText().toString();
                String password = mPasswordTIL.getText().toString();
                if (!Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches()) {
                    //invalid email pattern set error
                    mEmailET.setError("Invalid Email");
                    mEmailET.setFocusable(true);
                } else {
                    //valid email pattern
                    loginUser(email, password);
                }

            }
        });
        //not have account textview click
        notHaveAccountTv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, RegisterActivity.class));
                finish();
            }
        });
        //recover pass textview click
        mRecoverPassTv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showRecoverPasswordDialog();
            }
        });

        //handle google login btn click
        mGoogleLoginBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //begin google login process
                    Intent signInIntent = mGoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent();
                    startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
            }
        });

        //init progress dialog
        pd = new ProgressDialog(this);
        pd.setMessage("Logging In...");
    }

    private void showRecoverPasswordDialog() {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("Recover Password");

        //set layout linear layout
        LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
        //views to set in dialog
        final EditText emailEt = new EditText(this);
        emailEt.setHint("Email");
        emailEt.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_EMAIL_ADDRESS);
        emailEt.setMinEms(16);

        linearLayout.addView(emailEt);
        linearLayout.setPadding(10,10,10,10);

        builder.setView(linearLayout);

        //buttons recover
        builder.setPositiveButton("Recover", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                //input email
                String email = emailEt.getText().toString().trim();
                beginRecovery(email);
            }
        });

        //buttons cancel
        builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                //dismiss dialog
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        //show dialog
        builder.create().show();
    }

    private void beginRecovery(String email) {
        //show progress dialog
        pd.setMessage("Sending Email...");
        pd.show();
        mAuth.sendPasswordResetEmail(email).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                pd.dismiss();
                if (task.isSuccessful()){
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Email Sent", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else {
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Failed...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                pd.dismiss();
                //get and show proper error message
                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, ""+e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }

    private void loginUser(String email, String password) {
        //show progress dialog
        pd.setMessage("Logging In...");
        pd.show();
        mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        //display progress dialog
                        pd.dismiss();
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                            FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                            startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, ProfileActivity.class));
                            finish();
                        } else {
                            //display progress dialog
                            pd.dismiss();
                            // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Authentication failed.",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                //display progress dialog
                pd.dismiss();
                //error, get and show error message
                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "" + e.getMessage(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
        onBackPressed();
        return super.onSupportNavigateUp();
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(...);
        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data);
            try {
                // Google Sign In was successful, authenticate with Firebase
                GoogleSignInAccount account = task.getResult(ApiException.class);
                firebaseAuthWithGoogle(account);
            } catch (ApiException e) {
                // Google Sign In failed, update UI appropriately
                Toast.makeText(this, ""+e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        }
    }

    private void firebaseAuthWithGoogle(GoogleSignInAccount acct) {

        AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(acct.getIdToken(), null);
        mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information

                            FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                           // updateUI(user);
                        } else {
                            // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Login Failed...",  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            //Show user email in toast
                            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, ""+user.getEmail(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            //Go to profile activity after logged in
                            startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, ProfileActivity.class));
                            finish();
                            //updateUI(null);
                        }

                    }
                }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                //get and show error message
               Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, ""+e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }



}
```

And my build.gradle is

```
        apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.connex.connexsocial"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:21.1.1'
    implementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:17.0.0'
    //google sign in library
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:17.0.0'
}


apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 1):

The Error was in line 71 comment

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="20dp"
    android:background="#7ed957"
    tools:context=".LoginActivity">

  <TextView
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:textAlignment="center"
      android:text="Login"
      android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
      android:textSize="25sp" />

  <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
      style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TabLayout"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
      android:layout_centerVertical="true"
      android:id="@+id/emailET"
      app:passwordToggleEnabled="true">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:hint="email"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />
  </com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout>

  <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
      style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TabLayout"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
      android:layout_centerVertical="true"
      android:id="@+id/passwordTIL"
      android:layout_below="@id/emailET"
      app:passwordToggleEnabled="true">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:hint="password"
        android:layout_below="@id/emailET"
        app:passwordToggleEnabled="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

  </com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout>


  <Button
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="Login"
      android:layout_below="@id/passwordTIL"
      android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
      android:layout_centerVertical="true"
      style="@style/Base.CardView"
      android:id="@+id/login_btn"
      />

  <!---TextView: Click go to RegisterActivity-->
  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/nothave_accountTv"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="Don't have an account? Register Now"
      android:textAlignment="center"
      android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
      android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
      android:textColor="@color/colorBlack" />

  <!---TextView: Show dialog to recover password-->
  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/recoverPassTv"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:textAlignment="center"
      android:text="Forgot Password?"
      android:layout_below="@+id/login_btn" />

  <!---GoogleSignInBtn: Sign in with google account-->
  <com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton
      android:id="@+id/googleLoginBtn"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
      android:layout_below="@+id/recoverPassTv">
  </com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Remove extra '-' from comments

```
<!---TextView: Click go to RegisterActivity-->
```

Comment: If it's a comment, an extra character shouldn't matter

Comment: THANK YOU, goodness me something so simple lol this is my first app so thank you very much!

Comment: @cricket_007 `---` at the end is not allowed, see https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#sec-comments